# Creating catalog/schema/table in prestosql/presto container

Tags: presto, presto-jdbc, trino

I would like to use prestosql/presto container for automated tests. For this purpose I want to receive the ability to programmatically to create catalog/schema/table. Unfortunately, I didn't find the option via docker environment variables. If I trying to do it via jdbc connector, I receive following error:"This connector does not support creating tables"

How can I create schemas or tables using prestosql/presto container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing tests in Java (as suggested by JDBC tag), you can use [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) library. It comes with [Presto module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/presto/).

- uses `prestosql/presto` container under the hood
- comes with [Presto memory connector](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/memory.html) pre-installed, so you can create schemas & tables there

Comment: Thanks! I tried the framework and it fits my requirements

Comment: I encountered the same issue. Connecting to the "memory" catalog using the following JDBC string solved it for me: `jdbc:presto://localhost:8080/memory/default`